# Django 1.8 (Python 3.4): Show different templates based on user authorization with Class-Based Views

Tags: python, django, django-views, authorization

I'd like to have a Class-Based View 'homepage'. When a user visits 'homepage':

If the user is a guest, a guest function is called
If the user is logged in, a logged in function is called

The function called then sets the appropriate template and context.

Is this the proper way of doing this? And if so how? The documentation I've found only details this with function views.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would override [`get_template_names`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.get_template_names) to set the template name, and [`get_context_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data) to set the context data. You can access the user with `self.request.user`, and check whether they are logged in with the [`is_authenticated()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests) method.

```
class HomepageView(TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Returns a different context depending
        on whether the user is logged in or not
        """
        context = super(HomepageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            context['user_type'] = 'logged in'
        else:
            context['user_type'] = 'guest'
        return context

    def get_template_names(self):
        """
        Returns a different template depending
        on whether the user is logged in or not
        """
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return 'logged_in_homepage.html'
        else:
            return 'guest_homepage.html'
```

Note that I have overridden different methods of `TemplateView` to customize the functionality, rather than calling one method for guest or another method for logged in users that does everything. If you really want to call one method that does everything, then it might be better to use a function view instead.

Answer (score 1):

You know, your question is really open-ended. There are loads of different ways to do it.

I would probably subclass `TemplateView`, overwriting the `dispatch` method to set a different template based on the scenario.

To figure out how your logic fits in with the various CBVs, I recommend the [Classy Class-Based-Views](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.8/django.views.generic.base/TemplateView/) resource, so you can see which methods are called where.